Bulk copying DB objects from Synapse Serverless SQL pool
I have two databases, called DB1 and DB2 here for simplicity. DB1 is a Production DB and DB2 is a Dev environment, and I am working on setting up a proper CICD pipeline between them. However, DB2 has been allowed to get out of date with the objects in DB1 (don't ask how!).
I need to bulk generate CREATE OR ALTER scripts for all of the Views in DB1 so that I can apply them to DB2 in order to sync them back up.
In regular SQL Server this would be achievable within SSMS, using the "Generate Scripts" function. However, Serverless does not appear to have this function and I'm at a loss how best to achieve this.
I've looked at doing it with a Synapse Pipeline, selecting the VIEW_DEFINITION from DB1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS but can't find a reliable way of amending these values to be CREATE OR ALTERS rather than just CREATE (as a CREATE will fail if the view already exists on DB2, which is going to be the case 90% of the time).
Would anyone be able to suggest a way of doing this that is quicker than just manually scripting each view as an ALTER, please?

SSDT Projects support Synapse Serverless now so you can create a database project using one as a source (empty SSDT projects have an "import" option to import database object definitions from a server) and put that into source control and deploy to both from that https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/boost-your-cicd-automation-for-synapse-sql-serverless-by-taking/ba-p/3922851

In order to sync views between your production database (DB1) and your development environment (DB2), and to CREATE OR ALTER scripts for all views in DB1.
You Can try the below approach:
DECLARE @queryDef NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE view_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''' + QUOTENAME(o.name) + '''))
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql N''' + 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(UPPER(sm.definition), 'CREATE VIEW', 'ALTER VIEW'), 'DB1.', 'DB2.') + '''
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql N''' + 
    REPLACE(UPPER(sm.definition), 'DB1.', 'DB2.') + '''
END'
FROM sys.sql_modules sm
JOIN sys.objects o ON sm.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE o.type = 'V'
OPEN view_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM view_cursor INTO @queryDef
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @queryDef
    FETCH NEXT FROM view_cursor INTO @queryDef
END
CLOSE view_cursor
DEALLOCATE view_cursor

In the above code script loops through all views in DB1
For each view, it checks if the view already exists in DB2.
If it does, it alters the view; if it doesn’t, it creates the view.
Next the view definition is fetched and adjusted by replacing CREATE VIEW with ALTER VIEW and updating references from DB1 to DB2.
Reference: Is there a way to replace code and update a view using a tsql script

Is there a way to replace code and update a view using a tsql script
Can you please let me know if this is any match with your current issue?
